# Angular 6 - jquery lightbox

Tags: jquery, angular, html

I want to add jquery simple lightbox: http://dbrekalo.github.io/simpleLightbox/ to my app, my problem is, when I write static code it works well, images are coming from links = works, images in folder works, but when I write *ngFor directive to loop all images, it returns me error and lightbox is not opening but image is opening in other bookmark.

error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
at window.onload (fotografia:29)
```

**static code working:**

```
<div class="imageGallery1">
<a href="demo/images/4big.jpg" title="Caption for gallery item 1"><img src="demo/images/4small.jpg" alt="Gallery image 1" /></a>
<a href="demo/images/5big.jpg" title="Caption for gallery item 2"><img src="demo/images/5small.jpg" alt="Gallery image 2" /></a>
<a href="demo/images/6big.jpg" title="Caption for gallery item 3"><img src="demo/images/6small.jpg" alt="Gallery image 3" /></a>
</div>
```

**Dynamic not working**

component.html:

```
<div class="imageGallery1">
<a *ngFor="let image of galleryList; let i = index" [href]="image" title="Caption for gallery item {{i + 1}}"><img [src]="image" alt="Gallery image {{i + 1}}" /></a>
```

galleryList is an Array of string and have 3 positions with links of different photos

component.ts:

```
declare var $: any;
...
ngOnInit() {

$('.imageGallery1 a').simpleLightbox():

}
...
```

Comment: How the `galleryList` get the data? i

Comment: As i mentioned before, galleryList is an Array of string with 3 positiones

Comment: You need to use `ngAfterViewInit`, since in `ngOnInit` the html is not rendered yet. But the error looks weird, unless calling your lighbox on an empty set yields an error... **Note** Avoid using jQuery in angular projects...

Comment: Yeah i know that not use jquery, but i need lightbox :/ Is there any good lightbox and easy to use with angular 6 ?? :/ I didn't find anything interested

Comment: You can add is as answer it works well, please point me if you have some good angular 6 ligthbox

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ngx-Lightbox with Angular without the need for jQuery:-
https://github.com/themyth92/ngx-lightbox/tree/feature/upgradeAngular7

Comment: Can u please help me for ngx-lightbox issue, Actually my issue is when triggering lightbox, Instead of image name, Count is coming. How to solve this in ngx-lightbox.